# Joomla, the correct escaping in their own component

Tags: php, joomla

I have written a custom component for Joomla. This RSS feed can be read from different sources and should be stored in the SQL database.

But how do I use the escape function properly? Here is my code:

```
// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Insert columns.
$columns = array('id',
                 'id_feedsource', 
                 'title', 
                 'link', 
                 'pubDate', 
                 'timePubDate', 
                 'guid', 
                 'description', 
                 'creator', 
                 'content' , 
                 'read', 
                 'smart', 
                 'demografie', 
                 'urbanisierung', 
                 'arbeitswelten', 
                 'konnektivitaet', 
                 'nano', 
                 'femaleshift', 
                 'energie', 
                 'bildung', 
                 'individualisierung', 
                 'public', 
                 'cache');

// Insert values.
$values = array('NULL',
                $db->quote($db->escape($value['source'])),
                $db->quote($db->escape($value['title'])),
                $db->quote($db->escape($value['link'])),
                $db->quote($db->escape($value['pubDate'])),
                $db->quote($value['timePubDate']),
                $db->quote($db->escape($value['guid'])),
                $db->quote($db->escape($value['description'])),
                $db->quote($db->escape($value['creator'])),
                $db->quote($db->escape($value['content'])),
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

// Prepare the insert query.
$query
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__heka_rss_feeds'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
    ->values(implode(',', $values));

// Set the query object and execute it.
$db->setQuery($query);
//echo $query->dump().'<br>';
$db->execute();
```

Now add in individual contributions "\". For example:
**NASA\'s Fermi Space Telescope sharpens its high-energy vision**

When issuing this does not look nice. Because of the escaping SQL Injection is to be used, but it may not yet be correct.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the $db->quote also escapes the values. So you will have double escapes the way you did it. Try

```
$values = array('NULL',
            $db->quote($value['source']),
            $db->quote($value['title']),
            $db->quote($value['link']), 
            ...
```

...which should work better. See docs [here](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseQuery.html#method_quote)